# Progressive LED lighting

Tags: ios, iphone, led, light

I am trying to perform a progressive lighting with the iPhone LED. To do this, I tried to use the method `setTorchModeOnWithLevel`, with a floating value periodically increased, from 0.1 to `AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel`.

My problem is that the LED emits light "step by step". The light intensity seems to be the same from 0.1 to 0.33, then increases all of a sudden starting 0.34 and stays the same until 0.5, etc. There are in total only four different intensities of light.

I suspect this is a hardware limitation, but even after lots of Googling, I could not find any mention of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try any of the apps that are in the store that use the flash light, you will see that it happens the same, the intensity change is not smooth.

So, I suspect is a hardware limitation.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunately seems to be a hardware issue... Thanks for answering !